# Kendo Upload Control: Save upload response within Control

Tags: kendo-ui

I am new to Kendo UI Controls, and i have a question.

Currently I am using the upload control within a form to upload files to a API Service. This service returns an ID of the sent file, which must be sent at the moment of saving the whole form.

Is it possible to save the returned ID within the Upload Control and access that information at the moment of posting the form, or does that information has to be stored in a different field, at the success event handler?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but the Kendo UI Music Store http://www.kendouimusicstore.com/ sample app uses the Upload widget to add new album art. There is a bit of documentation here: http://docs.kendoui.com/tutorials/ASP.NET/Kendo%20Music%20Store/Music%20Store%20Web/kendo-music-store-web-management-grid#album-art-upload-(with-the-kendo-upload-widget) The way it does it is to upload immediately, and get the ID returned by the server in the `success` event handler. If you are posting the file with the rest of the form then it may work a little differently.

Comment: The sample helped indeed. The solution I came across was to upload the file when it is selected/dropped, and then, on the Success event handler fill a form field with the received ID.